# What is the replacement for drwtsn32 -p <PID>? OR how to do a PID stack trace in windows without installing anything

Tags: windows, stack-trace, built-in

For many years, I used drwtsn32 -p  when I needed a stack trace on a ***LOCKED DOWN*** customer computer and I needed a stack dump. Since then, I have been fortunate enough to not need this functionality but now I do.

Since Microsoft has pulled this application, is there another utility that is:

1. Easy to run ***without registry edits*** and the like.
2. ***No installation*** other than what windows (10/11) already has (aka built-in).

DrWtsn32.exe did this so I must assume that it was replaced with something since they pulled it.

Comment: ever find an answer? I am actually looking for the same thing.

Comment: @RileyHughes .. I am afraid I still have no answer to this.  Sorry.